# reorder column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, columnsorting

I am working with a vb.net project which have datagridview display through datasource from database. the datagridview will display is as follow.

| Item | Part | data 1 | data 2 | data 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | length | 2.60 | 2.65 | 2.69 |
| 2 | width | 22.30 | 22.29 | 22.28 |
| 3 | height | 16.30 | 16.27 | 16.31 |

How do I do if need to rearrange my table as follow when display datagridview?

| Item | data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | Part |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.60 | 2.65 | 2.69 | length |
| 2 | 22.30 | 22.29 | 22.28 | width |
| 3 | 16.30 | 16.27 | 16.31 | height |

If you can give the link to any related reference I also appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-enable-column-reordering-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the Columns

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-change-the-order-of-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

```
Private Sub AdjustColumnOrder()

With customersDataGridView
    .Columns("CustomerID").Visible = False
    .Columns("Item").DisplayIndex = 0
    .Columns("data 1").DisplayIndex = 1
    .Columns("data 2").DisplayIndex = 2
    .Columns("data 3").DisplayIndex = 3
    .Columns("Part").DisplayIndex = 4
End With
```

End Sub